# Find common elements between two string arrays (even duplicates)

Tags: java, discord

Ok, so I'm making a discord bot, and im dumb. 
So if the solution of the game is: [":star:", ":star:", ":star:", ":star:"] 
And I enter [":star:",":clubs:", ":star:", ":star:"]

I need the common string array to be: [":star:",":star:",":star:"]

This is what i tried:

```java
  private List<String> findCommonElement(String[] a, String[] b) {

        List<String> commonElements = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String s1 : a) {
            for (String s2 : b) {
                if (s1.equals(s2)) {
                    commonElements.add(s1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return commonElements;
    }
```

I realize its checking each elements position with the others array position, but I don't know. Make it not nested?

Comment: what is wrong with the way you are doing it? What is your actual output?

Comment: Solution: [:star:, :star:, :star:, :star:] 
My input: [:star:, :clubs:, :clubs:, :clubs:] 

Same elements: [:star:, :star:, :star:, :star:]
No matter how much of the same elements my input contains it will go to 4.

Comment: so are you trying to match `a[0]` with `b[0]`, `a[1]` with `b[1]`, `a[2]` with `b[2]` etc?

Comment: Is the input array and solution always going to be the same length? Also are you trying to compare the strings in each array at each index ( i.e a[0].equals(b[0]) and next iteration being a[1].equals(b[1]);)?

Comment: @ScaryWombat No, another example Solution: [:clubs:, :hearts:, :hearts:, :star:] My input: [:hearts:, :clubs:, :star:, :hearts:] Same elements: [:hearts:, :clubs:, :hearts:, :star:]. So in this case the element positions don't match but the strings do.

Comment: If you use a `Set` not a `List` then you will not have duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the if condition, before setting the break, you can simply change the b array at that position to another string that will cause the if condition to be false for that position in array b when the nested for loop gets called again.

```
 private List<String> findCommonElement2(String[] a, String[] b) {

    List<String> commonElements = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < b.length; x++) {

            if(a[i].equals(b[x])) {
                commonElements.add(a[i]);
                b[x] = "ignore";
                break;
            }                               
        }

    }

    return commonElements;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a Set and it will prevent the duplicate values from being added

```
    Set<String> commonElements = new HashSet<>();

    for (String s1 : a) {
        for (String s2 : b) {
            if (s1.equals(s2)) {
                commonElements.add(s1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return commonElements;
```

Comment: Yes but i want the duplicates.